# Css/images/javascript in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Concerning [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060733/codeigniter-loading-css) post, I'd like to add css,images and js to my codeigniter application. My question is after you add path to your header file `href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/moorainbow.css"` , where do you actually put your files, is it in system, application, view or controller? I found like 10 articles so far explaining the same procedure but no one is talking about where actual file should be kept? can anybody help me with this ? thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [this](http://codeignitercamp.blogspot.com/), meaning you need to put css files in the same level as system, meaning your webroot. Not inside system, not inside application etc in the web root. And read from the website rest ..

Answer (score 7):

Ok, try two. Here is the answer for Codeigniter (instead of CakePHP... sorry!)

Put any public files in the root (same directory as the main `index.php`)

```
index.php
system/
images/
js/
css/
```

My reference: http://www.greggoforth.net/article/5

Comment: I'm an idiot. I should -1 myself for not reading the question closely. My edit should provide what you want.