# load style css in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter - Loading CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060733/codeigniter-loading-css)

I try load css file and it's not work.
this is the link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application/styles/style.css" />
```

how i can do this?

Comment: check your path, use full path instead `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$baseurl}application/styles/style.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder outside the application folder Eg: resources/css/style.css and link it like below.

Then the folder structure will be like this,

```
-application
-resources
-system
-index.php

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/styles/style.css" />
```

Comment: it's not work.
base_url not work...

Comment: @user1702278 you have to declare it before using it..open `application/config/config.php` to change your `base_url()`

Comment: when you echo base_url(); what does it show? nothing? did you define $config['base_url'] in the config file (application/config/config.php)?

Comment: i change and it's dont work:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\LearnIL\application\views\layout\header.php on line 16

Comment: how did you define the $config['base_url']? it should be like this if you are using localhost, $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_app/'

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/LearnIL/';

Comment: you have to load the url_helper. $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); That's in application/config/autoload.php

Comment: now it's work, but i do this:

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/stylesheet.css" />

and it's not work.

Comment: View you page source and copy the link and past it onto the browser and check where does it go. Check if the generated link is correct.

Comment: This is because the. Htaccess,
bow it's work, i do this now:
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|uploads|media|assets),
and it's work. tnx!

Comment: ok. good, if your problem resloved, don't forget to mark as answer