# Sounds simple but It is not working: Import CSS in CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I Just downloaded CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and Trying to import css into via header_controller,

I have tried SOF: [CodeIgniter - Loading CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060733/codeigniter-loading-css), [CI_Help_page](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/162004/#778219) and [codeigniter CSS problem (*SitePoint Form Thread*)](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?594739-codeigniter-CSS-problem). I'm currunlty utterly confuse and Can't find the simple Answer. Does any one out there has a one step answer on how to Import CSS and JS on CodeIgniter version 2.1.3.

I have : `register.php`

```
<?php

class register extends  CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        //Get header
        $this->load->view('header');

        //Any other class
        $this->load->view('register');

    }
}
```

than `header.php`

```
<?php

?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

        <title>DMP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

Here is my project folders: [Project folders.png](http://cl.ly/image/1i3f3K2V2f0B) (incase you want to guid me on where can I place CSS)

Thanks.

Comment: What does not work for you? Is the URL you output wrong?

Comment: @hakre So When i add <Link rel="" .../> tag in header, The page goes blank and nothing gets outputted.

Comment: *"The page goes blank and nothing gets outputted"* - That's a very common error, please see the [PHP Error Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456), IIRC it's the first entry there.

Comment: load the url helper in your controller... $this->load->helper('url') and follow the comment of @hakre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only guessing, but in order to be able to use base_url() you need to load the url helper in your controller. Also, as @hakre already said in the comments turn on your error reporting.

```
class register extends  CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        //Get header
        $this->load->view('header');

        //Any other class
        $this->load->view('register');

    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, Master piece of line ever! You can Thumbs-up to my que. if you like.

Comment: To add on to that, 1) autoloading the URL helper is extremely useful, and 2) `base_url` accepts a string argument for anything that should come after the base URL. It makes outputting easier. E.g. `echo base_url('css/bootstrap.css');`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/bootstrap.css')?>" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your view page:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```